# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS kernel 5.0.0-25-generic nvidia driver 440 not working with graphics card model GP107M GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

I've tried everything but nothing works

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
        Subsystem: Dell Device 086f
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
    --
    01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Dell GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
    01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

`modprobe nvidia`

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-25-generic

root@Blackpearl8819:~# sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
amd64-microcode intel-microcode iucode-tool libnvidia-common-440 thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
libnvidia-cfg1-430 libnvidia-common-430 libnvidia-compute-430 libnvidia-compute-430:i386 libnvidia-decode-430
libnvidia-decode-430:i386 libnvidia-encode-430 libnvidia-encode-430:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-430 libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386 libnvidia-gl-430
libnvidia-gl-430:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-430 libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-430 nvidia-dkms-430 nvidia-kernel-common-430
nvidia-kernel-source-430 nvidia-utils-430 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430
The following packages will be REMOVED:
libnvidia-cfg1-440 libnvidia-compute-440 libnvidia-compute-440:i386 libnvidia-decode-440 libnvidia-decode-440:i386
libnvidia-encode-440 libnvidia-encode-440:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-440 libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386 libnvidia-gl-440 libnvidia-gl-440:i386
libnvidia-ifr1-440 libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-440 nvidia-dkms-440 nvidia-driver-440 nvidia-kernel-common-440
nvidia-kernel-source-440 nvidia-utils-440 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libnvidia-cfg1-430 libnvidia-common-430 libnvidia-compute-430 libnvidia-compute-430:i386 libnvidia-decode-430
libnvidia-decode-430:i386 libnvidia-encode-430 libnvidia-encode-430:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-430 libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386 libnvidia-gl-430
libnvidia-gl-430:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-430 libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-430 nvidia-dkms-430 nvidia-driver-430
nvidia-kernel-common-430 nvidia-kernel-source-430 nvidia-utils-430 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430
0upgraded, 21 newly installed, 20 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 108 MB of archives.
After this operation, 51.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-cfg1-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [70.6 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-common-430 all 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [9,820 B]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-compute-430 i386 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [21.0 MB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-compute-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [20.2 MB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-decode-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [1,031 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-decode-430 i386 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [1,082 kB]  
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-encode-430 i386 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [50.1 kB]   
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-encode-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [50.4 kB] 
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-fbc1-430 i386 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [41.2 kB]     
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-fbc1-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [44.1 kB]  
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-gl-430 i386 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [17.3 MB]      
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-gl-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [32.8 MB]    
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-ifr1-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [68.5 kB]  
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-ifr1-430 i386 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [61.6 kB]    
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-compute-utils-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [73.0 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-kernel-source-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [12.0 MB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-kernel-common-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [9,804 B]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-dkms-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [25.8 kB]     
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-utils-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [337 kB]     
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [1,482 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-driver-430 amd64 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 [404 kB]    
Fetched 108 MB in 1min 55s (941 kB/s)                                                                                                  
(Reading database ... 152459 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nvidia-driver-440 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-cfg1-440:amd64 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-encode-440:amd64 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-decode-440:amd64 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing nvidia-utils-440 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-encode-440:i386 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-decode-440:i386 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-compute-440:i386 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-fbc1-440:amd64 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-ifr1-440:amd64 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-gl-440:amd64 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-gl-440:i386 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing nvidia-compute-utils-440 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing nvidia-dkms-440 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
INFO:Disable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing nvidia-kernel-common-440 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing nvidia-kernel-source-440 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Removing libnvidia-compute-440:amd64 (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-cfg1-430:amd64.
(Reading database ... 151855 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libnvidia-cfg1-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-cfg1-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-common-430.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libnvidia-common-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-common-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-compute-430:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libnvidia-compute-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-compute-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libnvidia-compute-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-decode-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libnvidia-decode-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-decode-430:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libnvidia-decode-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-encode-430:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libnvidia-encode-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-encode-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libnvidia-encode-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libnvidia-fbc1-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-fbc1-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libnvidia-fbc1-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-gl-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libnvidia-gl-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-gl-430:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libnvidia-gl-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libnvidia-ifr1-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libnvidia-ifr1-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-compute-utils-430.
Preparing to unpack .../14-nvidia-compute-utils-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-compute-utils-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-source-430.
Preparing to unpack .../15-nvidia-kernel-source-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-source-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-common-430.
Preparing to unpack .../16-nvidia-kernel-common-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-common-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-dkms-430.
Preparing to unpack .../17-nvidia-dkms-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-dkms-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-utils-430.
Preparing to unpack .../18-nvidia-utils-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-utils-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430.
Preparing to unpack .../19-xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-driver-430.
Preparing to unpack .../20-nvidia-driver-430_430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-driver-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-common-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libnvidia-common-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-cfg1-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-compute-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-compute-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-source-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up nvidia-dkms-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
Loading new nvidia-430.50 DKMS files...
Building for 5.0.0-25-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for kernel 5.0.0-25-generic was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up nvidia-utils-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up nvidia-compute-utils-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Warning: The home dir /nonexistent you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 122) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 127) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 122) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/nonexistent'.
Setting up libnvidia-encode-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up nvidia-driver-430 (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-25-generic
```

---

```
nvidia-smi
Fri Nov 15 21:13:10 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.50       Driver Version: 430.50       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    307MiB /  4040MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      4859      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           151MiB |
|    0      5619      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         101MiB |
|    0      6921      G   ...uest-channel-token=13487657900999098837    52MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101096/discussion-on-question-by-sheik-imran-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-kernel-5-0-0-25-generic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Module build for kernel 5.0.0-25-generic was skipped since the kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
```

That is the reason why you can't install any driver. You don't have kernel headers installed.

Install it by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

this will update the kernel and install the headers.

Reboot and the driver should build and install by itself if Secure Boot is off.

Comment: And you can install 440 if you like.

Comment: Could you please check my question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368010/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-error-when-running-nvidia-smi-in-ubuntu-18-nvidia-smi-has-fa  Thank you very much in advance.