# Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS Error when running nvidia-smi in Ubuntu 18 "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver."

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda, gpu

As shown in the below photo I have the nvidia 470 driver installed on my Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS but when I run nvidia-smi it gives the error `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`

I noticed in the settings that the graphics card model is not appearing and says "unknown".

I've also noticed that the Graphics is set to "llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)" although in the settings the nvidia 470 is chosen.

I've did some googling and found that some suggestions are to disable the secure boot so I checked and found out that the secure boot is already off.

I've also removed the nvidia driver and reinstalled as per [these steps](https://gist.github.com/espoirMur/65cec3d67e0a96e270860c9c276ab9fa) but still after rebooting the same issue.

Any advice please?

When running `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'` this is the result:

```
0000:17:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e30 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 12ba
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
0000:17:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f7 (rev a1)
--
0000:73:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e30 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 12ba
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
0000:73:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f7 (rev a1)
--
0000:a6:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e30 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 12ba
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
0000:a6:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f7 (rev a1)
```

The output of `dkms status` is:

```
nvidia, 470.74: added
nvidia-fs, 2.7.53: added
oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22, 0.2, 4.15.0-1027-oem, x86_64: installed
```

[image]

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 As mentioned in my question, I went into the Bios setup and found that it's already disabled.

Comment: What is the adapter?

Comment: @Pilot6 what do you mean by "the adapter"?

Comment: What is the video adapter? Add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'` to the question

Comment: @Pilot6 I've added the output to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130338/discussion-between-tak-and-pilot6).

Comment: The driver didn't install. What does `dkms status` show? Maybe kernel is too old for the driver, etc.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've added the output to the question

Comment: Where did you get the 470.74 driver?  I thought the 470.63.01 was the latest one from the (20.04) standard repos.

Comment: @ubfan1 I followed the steps here https://gist.github.com/espoirMur/65cec3d67e0a96e270860c9c276ab9fa

Comment: @Pilot6 I remember I did the Ubuntu software updates and probably it included linux-headers which might have caused the issue? as it was working before normally before the update. Currently it is linux-headers-5.4.0-87-generic maybe I should downgrade to the previous one? and if so, then how I can do that?

Comment: There are lots of nvidia packages not starting with nvidia.  See the output of dpkg -l |grep nvidia    The initial delete of nvidia pacakges should include all those found. I'm running the 5.4 kernel on 20.04, and as I said, the 470.63.01 is what I have in my nvidia package names.